# How to send $user 's variable in loadable file by ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a variable user and i can send it in mPost.php file, but how I can to send it in loadable mLoad.php file before this script starting.? Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#message_area").load('mLoad.php');

$("#userArea").submit(function(){
    $.post('mPost.php', $('#userArea').serialize(), function(data){
        $("#message_area").append(data);
        });

    return false;
});
});
```

Comment: $.get('mLoad.php', {variable:'data'}, function(response){$('#message_area').html(response);});

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work. error : "Notice: Undefined index: user in C:\web\source\mLoad.php on line 7"

Comment: In mLoad you have to put `$user = $_GET['variable']`;

Comment: sorry i was not right, it is working, thank you.

Comment: Would you mind marking my answer as correct? Thanks

Comment: I haven't enough reputation(

Comment: Don't upvote, just check the answer box :) you get rep for it too.

Comment: How right to send more than 1 variable?

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the variable to the script first:

```
$.get('mLoad.php', {variable:'data'}, function(response){
    $('#message_area').html(response);
});
```